# Get the Object ID in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense

I want to know what is the Object ID of a certain object on the sheet. I downloaded an extension form (http://branch.qlik.com/#/project/56f591b33f1dca10d1e91865), and I need the object ID as parameter to extension to be able to export the data of certain object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and pasted answer from [Qlik](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/1.0/Subsystems/Workbench/Content/BuildingWebsites/HowTos/qswb_mup_obtainobjectid.htm)

> Obtaining object id using the Single feature
>
> One way of obtaining app id and object id is to use the Single feature
>   that comes with Qlik Sense.
>
> Do the following:
>
> Make sure that Qlik Sense Desktop is running. Open a browser window
>   and enter URL http://localhost:4848/single A list of available Qlik
>   Sense apps is displayed. Select the applicable Qlik Sense app. For
>   example, select the Tutorial.qvf item. A list of all sheets and
>   objects contained in the Qlik Sense app is displayed. If you want the
>   appid this can be found after the ?appid= in the URL. In this example
>   the appid is Tutorial.qvf Select the applicable Qlik Sense object. For
>   example, select the bar chart item titled Customer Sales and Quantity.
>   The visualization is displayed in the browser window. If you want the
>   object id, this can be found after the &obj in the URL. In this
>   example the object id is hpTGYJp. You have now obtained the object id
>   for the selected Qlik Sense object.

Comment: Whilst this is the correct answer, I don't think it's particularly straightforward! hopefully the functionality will be improved in 3.0

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. such a great way to turn around the failure (or the limitation) of Qlik Sense.

the appid is looks like:
C%3A%5CUsers%5Czsalem%5CDocuments%5CQlik%5CSense%5CApps%5CHS_Report.qvf


It is only (5CHS_Report.qvf) or the whole one with replacing the % with "space" I mean it look like:
C 3A 5CUsers 5Czsalem 5CDocuments 5CQlik 5CSense 5CApps 5CHS_Report.qvf

?

Comment: you need to click on the object you want to see, mine says C%3A%5CUsers%5Ccjohnson%5CDocuments%5CQlik%5CSense%5CApps%5CExecutive%20Dashboard.qvf&obj=MdpsUpA&opt=nointeraction&select=clearall the bit you want is obj=MdpsUpA

Comment: Yep, That is correct. I could notice that, but my last question was about the appid: the url is:
<iframe src='http://localhost:4848/single?appid=C%3A%5CUsers%5Czsalem%5CDocuments%5CQlik%5CSense%5CApps%5CHS_Report.qvf&obj=TVKSprG&opt=nointeraction&select=clearall' frameborder='0'></iframe>

so here the object ID is "TVKSprG" but for the appid it is a little bit ambiguous. Is the appid to is: "5CHS_Report.qvf" or
"C 3A 5CUsers 5Czsalem 5CDocuments 5CQlik 5CSense 5CApps 5CHS_Report.qvf " with the spaces or with out the spaces like:
"C3A5CUsers5Czsalem5CDocuments5CQlik5CSense5CApps5CHS_Report.qvf"

Comment: Sorry don't have access at the moment, but I think that's covered on the link for qlik in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an official tool in Dev Hub to inspect IDs of objects, have a look [at the docs](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2021/Subsystems/Mashups/Content/Sense_Mashups/Howtos/mashups-obtain-app-object-id.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Quicker alternative solution:

1. go to the application in a browser
2. open up the DevTools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+i), and select the "Elements" tab (in Chrome, could have a different name in other browsers, basically select the tab that shows you the generated DOM of the page)
3. search for "***cell qv-gridcell qvt-gridcell ng-scope qv-gridcell-acc-focus***", the elements with this class combination are going to be the qlik objects, their ***tid*** property is the object id you're looking for